# Problema para cargar scripts en vistal parcial usando "tabs" - Asp.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo problemas al ejecutar mi un script en mi vista parcial, cuando está vista parcial se ejecuta desde el tab1 se carga sin problemas mi script pero cuando ejecuto mi tab2 tengo scripts que no se ejecuta y me da error.

Cúal puede serla causa del error, mis scripts se encuentran el layout principal.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/js/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdata.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxresponse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxnumberinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxwindow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxdata.export.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.export.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxgrid.grouping.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxtabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/demos.js"></script>
```

Código que ejecuta un Action que contiene devuelve script y lo envía a mi vista parcial tab2.

```
<div class="formulario-datos2">
        <h3 style="margin-top:2px; text-align:center">Stock Actual de Productos</h3>

        @Html.Action("ObtieneStockActual")

    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]